# Challenges of Industrial-Scale Fermentation

Tags: microbiology, cell-culture

I was reading the wikipedia article on [industrial fermentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Industrial_fermentation), and it mentions that

> It is well established in the field of industrial microbiology that what works well at the laboratory scale may work poorly or not at all when first attempted at large scale.

Why is that?  What are the barriers to large-scale fermentation of bacterial culture?

Also, I know that cell cultures have distinct phases of growth and decay, but what happens after the cells die?  Would an industrial fermentation process have to "re-culture" the bacteria?